# Django dynamically add form to formset with google map autosuggest

Tags: javascript, django, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, django-forms

I have a javascript to add form dynamic to a form set for django and it is working

```
<input type="button" value="Add form" id="add_more">

<script>
    $('#add_more').click(function () {
        var form_idx = $('#id_parties-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
        $('#form_set').append($('#empty_form').html().replace(/__prefix__/g, form_idx));
        $('#id_parties-TOTAL_FORMS').val(parseInt(form_idx) + 1);
    });
    ;
</script>
```

by clicking the Add form, it will add one more form to my django formset.

But since in my empty form i have a field to use google map autosuggest:

```
<script>
    function initialize() {
        var input_location = document.getElementById('id_parties-__prefix__-location');
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input_location);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

how to make it working for the location field in this extra forms too?

---

edit:

the empty form in short:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="{{ form.location.label }}" class="col-sm-3 control-label"> {{ form.location.label }}:</label>

        <div class="col-sm-9">
            {{ form.location.errors }}
            {{ form.location }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script>
    function initialize() {
        var input_location = document.getElementById('{{ form.location.auto_id }}');
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input_location);

        var g_autocomplete = $("body > .pac-container").filter(":visible");
        g_autocomplete.bind('DOMNodeInserted DOMNodeRemoved', function (event) {
            $(".pac-item", this).addClass("needsclick");
        });
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
```

thanks a lot.

Comment: anyone can help on this one? thanks. think for 2 days already..

Comment: Could you add the HTML?

Comment: Specifically, what's inside `#empty_form`?

Comment: `$('#form_set').children('input:last')` will match the last `<input>` element in `#form_set`. Does `{{ form.location }}` render to a location input? If so, my answer should work since there are no input elements after `{{ form.location }}` in your code.

Comment: check my example below? there are 4 fields.
and there are two locations fields
and how about to get the element by id? how to do it?
thanks

Comment: I wouldn't select the inputs by ID. Even if they have an ID, you're duplicating the elements when you extend the form and that results in duplicate IDs. Can you check the generated HTML to see if the inputs have a `name` attribute?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, in your click-handler you need to do the following:

1. Match the last added `input` element with jQuery. This will return a jQuery object.
2. Get the underlying plain JavaScript object by using `[0]`.
3. Create the auto-complete input using the plain JavaScript object.

Let's assume your `#empty_form` looks like this.

```
<form id="empty_form">
    <input type="text"/>
</form>
```

Then you can dynamically initialize the auto-complete inputs by using the following snippet ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rr4a262s/2/)).

```
$('#add_more').click(function () {
    ...

    var input = $('#form_set').children('input:last')[0];
    new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
});
```

If the content of `#empty_form` is more complex, it might get a little more complicated but the basic procedure remains the same.