# google map api autosuggest: change restriction dynamically from another address

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

i am using google map api v3 for gmap automcomplete. may i ask how to set the biased country and city from another address dynamically?

this is my existing code:

```
<script>
    function initialize() {
        var input_location = document.getElementById('id_location');
        var options_location = {
            componentRestrictions: {country: 'fr'}
        };
        var autocomplete_location = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input_location);

    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

From above you can see i restrict the search to france.

But how about i want to change the country based on another address?

example: 
Geneva International Airport, Grand-Saconnex, Switzerland

Thanks a lot

---

edit:

one more question ( but this question is closely related with what i am asking above, so i do not ask a new q.)
what if the addres is different?
example:
a1: brazil
a2: Geneva International Airport, Grand-Saconnex, Switzerland

from the address_components, i should not always extract the second element as the country.

edit2:

problem solved. i wrote a for loop to check if 'country' is in types to get the country code:

```
geocoder.geocode({address: address}, function (result, status) {
                if (status === 'OK' && result.length > 0) {
                    var i = 0;
                    len = result[0].address_components.length;
                    for (; i < len; i++){
                        if (result[0].address_components[i].types.indexOf('country') >= 0) {
                            c_code = result[0].address_components[i].short_name;
                        }
                    }

                    var options = {
                        componentRestrictions: {country: c_code }
                    };

                    var input_location = document.getElementById('id_location');
                    var autocomplete_location = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input_location, options);

                }
            })
```

Comment: It might help to know from where you get the other address.

Comment: from another text
or from another django object in template
example:
{{ party.location }}

thanks

Comment: So is your problem how to get the country code out of that address or how to apply the country code to the autocomplete?

Comment: how to get the country code out of that address

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you have two options: create a static mapping or use geocoding.

#### Static Mapping

Just setup an object that statically maps country long names (like `Switzerland`) to short names (like `CH`). Afterwards, determine the country long name from your address by means of common string manipulation functions. You can then simply look up the short name in the mapping object.

```
var countries = {
    'switzerland': 'CH',
    'germany': 'DE',
    ...
}

var address = 'Geneva International Airport, Grand-Saconnex, Switzerland';
var country = address.substring(address.lastIndexOf(',') + 1);
var code = countries[country.trim().toLowerCase()];
```

Note that this option does only work if you know all of the countries upfront.

#### Geocoding

Another way to approach your problem is to geocode the address string and then read the country code from the response.

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode({
    address: 'Geneva International Airport, Grand-Saconnex, Switzerland'
}, function(result, status) {
    if (status === 'OK' && result.length > 0) {
        var code = result[0].address_components[2].short_name;
    }
});
```

This alternative does not require you to know all the countries upfront. There is, however, a rate limit in the geocoding API which you might run into.

Comment: thanks! the second solution is what i am aiming for!

btw, do you have any idea for this q as well? i have been thinking this for a few days, thanks a lot!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25533192/django-dynamically-add-form-to-formset-with-google-map-autosuggest

Answer (score 10):

Use the `setComponentRestrictions()` method of the `Autocomplete` class. See the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=sv#Autocomplete).

```
var country = 'fr';
var autocomplete_location = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input_location);

autocomplete_location.setComponentRestrictions({'country': country});
```

Comment: ya i knew to set the setComponentRestrictions to get biased result.
but anyway to get the country code from a text address?

example: Geneva International Airport, Grand-Saconnex, Switzerland

thanks

Comment: geocoder.geocode({address: address}, function (result, status) {
               if (status === 'OK' && result.length > 0) {
                    c_code = result[0].address_components[0].short_name;
                    alert("Geocode was aaa successful for the following reason: " + c_code);
                }
            })

            var options = {
                types: ['(cities)'],
                componentRestrictions: {country: c_code }
            };

            alert("Geocode was successful for the following reason: " + c_code);

the first alert is alerted, but the seoncd alert is not

Comment: What are you trying to do and where do you want to apply the componentRestrictions?

Answer (score 0):

Since it may be difficult to change multiple options, it might be better to remove previous listener and create new one with changed options.

Clear current listener:

```
var autocompleteField = document.getElementById("autocomplete");
google.maps.event.clearInstanceListeners(autocompleteField);
```

Add new listener depending on e.g. checkbox:

```
var onlySlovakia = document.getElementById("checkboxOnlySlovakia");

// common restriction
var options = {}

if(onlySlovakia.value == "1"){
    // we want more detailed suggestions
    options.ComponentRestrictions = {country : 'sk'};
    options.types: ['geocode', 'establishment']
}else{
    options.types: ['geocode']
}

// create instance
handle = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(autocompleteField, options);

// add listener with new options
google.maps.event.addListener(handle, 'place_changed', function() {
    var place = handle.getPlace();
    ... process results ...
});
```

See also [API event namespace](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#event).